# What is this icon on status bar?

Tags: notification-bar

I just realized there is new icon in my status bar on left of sound icon

[image]

I don't have clue what is that icon, thus I also can't search information about it.

Anyone has advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the **Battery Stamina Mode** (Two hands holding the battery).

[image: Screenshot_Battery_Stamina_Mode]

> Battery STAMINA Mode builds on the same technology as [Extended
>   Standby Mode](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/10/05/learn-about-extended-standby-mode-sonys-new-power-save-feature-video/). You can turn it off if your dont want it in the
>   Power management Settings page.
>
> Starting one minute after the screen has been turned off, data traffic
>   is automatically blocked and background activities are prevented from
>   waking up the system.
>
> When Battery STAMINA Mode is running, you will also get power
>   management tips to help you save even more energy, and keep your
>   device going even longer. For example, if Battery STAMINA Mode is
>   turned off and you leave your device with the screen turned off for
>   six hours or more, you will get a recommendation in the notification
>   bar to turn on Battery STAMINA Mode. You will also be notified about
>   apps that consume a lot of power. [[Ref.](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/04/03/how-sonys-battery-stamina-mode-works/)]

You can also White list some imporatant apps, thus allowing them to run in the background.

Read More on [How battery Stamina Mode works](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/04/03/how-sonys-battery-stamina-mode-works/)?

[image: Screenshot_stamina_mode]